# MySql - count records since last time it was X o'clock

Tags: mysql, date, select

I need to count records created since it was last 9:00am.

so at 8:59am I need to count all records since yesterday at 9:00am and at 9:01am I will need to count since today at 9:00am,

data sample

```
    ID    |   created
----------------------------------
    1     |   2018-11-13 17:00
    2     |   2018-11-13 09:00
    3     |   2018-11-13 08:01
    4     |   2018-11-12 13:00
    5     |   2018-11-11 17:31
```

running the query at 13-11-2018 8:59am should return **2** (rows 3,4)

running the query at 13-11-2018 9:01am should return **1** (rows 2)

the query I'm looking for should be something like:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM myTable WHERE created > "TIME_SINCE_9AM()"
```

any help?

Comment: Can you please add example data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution, I hoped for a prettier query but it works...

I'm using IF statement to determine if right now is before 9am or after and running count on records accordingly, (the H var is for testing purposes, if you put 18 in there it works since last 18:00)

```
SET @H = "9"; 

SELECT 
    IF (TIMEDIFF(NOW(), SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (-@H) HOUR))<0,
        SUM(CASE WHEN created>SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (-@H+24) HOUR) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN created>SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (-@H) HOUR) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    ) counter
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Good that you have solved it. You should mark it as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)